# C# Percentage Decoding

Tags: c#, urlencode

I am trying to decode a percentage encoded string passed from a  PHP script to my C# application. The PHP encrypts the data, so there are many special characters that I percentage encode.

Here's the string I'm passing in the URL:

> %C9%90%04L%EFEA%D1U%AFi%CBc%3A%E5%D0%40Q%D6%1Bn%C9%C3%B5%0FT%FC%E5h%95m%EF%BF%24tB%A6%D1%08%3B%83%A1%CF%1B%99Zo%02

But it has trouble percentage decoding parts of it: when I fetch the query string, like so:

```
var queryString = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString;
var token = queryString["token"];
```

The variable `token`, though, equals this:

> %C9%90%04L%EF%BF%BDEA%EF%BF%BDU%EF%BF%BDI%EF%BF%BDC%3A%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%40Q%EF%BF%BD%1BN%EF%BF%BD%C3%B5%0FT%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BDH%EF%BF%BDM%EF%BF%BD%24TB%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%08%3B%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%1B%EF%BF%BDZO%02

This is definitely not what I put into the query string. When looking at it, the first time it messes up is `%EF`(starts 11th character into the original query string). Instead of `%EF` it shows: `%EF%BF%BD`. When I searched a little, I found [this webpage](http://www.cogsci.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.cgi?input=%F6&mode=char) which says the "Hex UTF-8 Bytes" are EF BF BD.

EDIT:

Forgot to mention, QueryString looks like this:

> token=%c9%90%04L%ef%bf%bdEA%ef%bf%bdU%ef%bf%bdi%ef%bf%bdc%3a%ef%bf%bd%ef%bf%bd%40Q%ef%bf%bd%1bn%ef%bf%bd%c3%b5%0fT%ef%bf%bd%ef%bf%bdh%ef%bf%bdm%ef%bf%bd%24tB%ef%bf%bd%ef%bf%bd%08%3b%ef%bf%bd%ef%bf%bd%ef%bf%bd%1b%ef%bf%bdZo%02&oauth_token_secret=S%23%2bw%ef%bf%bd%ef%bf%bdX%17%ef%bf%bd0%ef%bf%bd%60%ef%bf%bd%ef%bf%bd%ef%bf%bd%ef%bf%bd*%ef%bf%bdi%08%ef%bf%bd%ef%bf%bd%ef%bf%bd%ef%bf%bd%07%ef%bf%bd%12RS07%ef%bf%bdgl%1e%ef%bf%bd%d7%832%d1%a1%ef%bf%bd%275%ef%bf%bdv%ef%bf%bd

Comment: By the way, I'm developing with .NET

Comment: What does the full URL look like including the querystring?  Is "%C9%90..." the data or the querystring encoded form of the data?

Comment: @David Please see edit

Comment: Obviously I don't know your requirements, but it seems to me like you are going about this in a more difficult way than is necessary.

Comment: @Casey How so? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It just seems like passing in a string that originally have percent signs to the URL is asking for trouble decoding it.  When I had somewhat similar problems I used base-32 to get the content into a purely alphanumeric format for the URL.

Comment: @Casey Maybe I should just put the tokens inside the HTTP Body?

Comment: If that's an option I think it would be better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be looking for the [HttpServerUtility.UrlDecode method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6196h3wt(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlDecode(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["token"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error is somewhere else...

I created a new web page in a .Net 4.0 project, and put this in the Page_Load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var queryString = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString;
    var token = queryString["token"];
    throw new Exception(token);
}
```

Then I ran the page by going to this URL which matches the querystring you gave above:

> http://localhost:27151/test.aspx?token=%c9%90%04L%ef%bf%bdEA%ef%bf%bdU%ef%bf%bdi%ef%bf%bdc%3a%ef%bf%bd%ef%bf%bd%40Q%ef%bf%bd%1bn%ef%bf%bd%c3%b5%0fT%ef%bf%bd%ef%bf%bdh%ef%bf%bdm%ef%bf%bd%24tB%ef%bf%bd%ef%bf%bd%08%3b%ef%bf%bd%ef%bf%bd%ef%bf%bd%1b%ef%bf%bdZo%02

The page decoded the `token` and displayed it in the exception message as this:

> ɐL�EA�U�i�c:��@Q�n�õT��h�m�$tB��;����Zo

(The URL is encoding a binary string so when the actual string is printed, there are some characters that don't get displayed.)

If you run this and the `token` actually prints "%C9%90%04L..." then your token has probably been double encoded.  All of the percent signs will be replaced with "%25" so your URL would look like this:

> http://localhost:27151/test.aspx?token=%25c9%2590%2504L%25ef%25bf%25bdEA%25ef%25bf%25bdU%25ef%25bf%25bdi%25ef%25bf%25bdc%253a%25ef%25bf%25bd%25ef%25bf%25bd%2540Q%25ef%25bf%25bd%251bn%25ef%25bf%25bd%25c3%25b5%250fT%25ef%25bf%25bd%25ef%25bf%25bdh%25ef%25bf%25bdm%25ef%25bf%25bd%2524tB%25ef%25bf%25bd%25ef%25bf%25bd......

Since you didn't mention the "%25", the error is somewhere else in your code.  The URL you think you are using is not the one being decoded.

Comment: There are no %25 in the OP's question. If you are going to display bu=inary bytes please use hexadecimal.

Comment: Correct.  I've added that as a conclusion.  All of that was to show that the OP's problem is somewhere else...